# NetTcpPortSharing process won't start on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: tcp, service, net

I have a problem in Windows Server 2012 R2 : I have searched and try everything I know to fix this, but I cannot start NetTcpPortSharing service and therefore I cannot configure Windows Server Essentials Role, among other things.

I have theses services not starting :

- gupdate (Google Update)
- NetTcpActivator
- ADWS (keeps restarting (115 times in a few hours))
- WseNtfSvc
- NetTcpPortSharing
- ServiceProviderRegistry
- NetPipeActivator

A lot of them depend on NetTcpPortSharing service I believe. I've been googling for a day now and haven't found anything. I tried ProcessMonitor but no particular error.

The domain is quite new and reinstalling is not an option here. I'd really appreciate help guys I don't know what to do here (for any of these services) any help appeciated!

```
Une demande de démarrage du service a échoué.
 Code d'erreur : System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Le type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink.Behavior, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' inscrit pour l'extension 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink.Behavior' n'a pas pu être chargé. (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config line 254)
   à System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.EvaluateOne(String[] keys, SectionInput input, Boolean isTrusted, FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult)
   à System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.Evaluate(FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult, Boolean getLkg, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   à System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   à System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   à System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   à System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   à System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey)
   à System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
   à System.ServiceModel.Activation.AspNetEnvironment.UnsafeGetSectionFromConfigurationManager(String sectionPath)
   à System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ConfigurationHelpers.UnsafeGetAssociatedSection(ContextInformation evalContext, String sectionPath)
   à System.ServiceModel.Configuration.CommonBehaviorsSection.UnsafeGetSection()
   à System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadServiceDescription(ServiceHostBase host, ServiceDescription description, ServiceElement serviceElement, Action`1 addBaseAddress, Boolean skipHost)
   à System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.LoadConfigurationSectionInternal(ConfigLoader configLoader, ServiceDescription description, ServiceElement serviceSection)
   à System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.ApplyConfiguration()
   à System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeDescription(UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses)
   à System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost..ctor(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
   à System.ServiceModel.Activation.SharingService.StartControlService()
   à System.ServiceModel.Activation.SharingService.Start()
   à System.ServiceModel.Activation.TcpPortSharing.OnStart(String[] args)
 Nom du processus : SMSvcHost
 ID du processus : 3736
```

--

```
 Application : Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.WebServices.exe
    Version du Framework : v4.0.30319
    Description : le processus a été arrêté en raison d'une exception non gérée.
    Informations sur l'exception : System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
    Pile :
       à System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(System.String, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, System.Object ByRef, System.Object ByRef)
       à System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(System.String)
       à System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(System.String)
       à System.ServiceModel.Activation.AspNetEnvironment.UnsafeGetSectionFromConfigurationManager(System.String)
       à System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ConfigurationHelpers.UnsafeGetAssociatedSection(System.Configuration.ContextInformation, System.String)
       à System.ServiceModel.Configuration.CommonBehaviorsSection.UnsafeGetSection()
       à System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadServiceDescription(System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase, System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceDescription, System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServiceElement, System.Action`1<System.Uri>, Boolean)
       à System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.LoadConfigurationSectionInternal(System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader, System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceDescription, System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServiceElement)
       à System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.ApplyConfiguration()
       à System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeDescription(System.ServiceModel.UriSchemeKeyedCollection)
       à System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost..ctor(System.Type, System.Uri[])
       à Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.WebServices.ADWSHost..ctor(System.Uri[])
       à Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.WebServices.ADWSHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(System.String, System.Uri[])
       à Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.WebServices.WindowsHostService.StartService(System.Object)
       à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
       à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
       à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
       à System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart(System.Object)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it ! As I couldn't reinstall .Net Framework (it would uninstall way too much roles) I did it the "hard" way : I took a Microsoft.NET folder from a Windows 8.1 PC that had the exact same version installed, copied it in there, changed the permissions to local system and there you go : NetTcpPortSharing then all the other services started !